# How can I implement google play GAMES sign in?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I got my google sign in working (although it sometimes gives me `handleSignInResult: false`) with a custom xml layout from [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) `SignInActivity.java`, but now I need that the user can sign in to the Google Play Games with the option to choose which email to pick and I want this kind of style that a lot of android games are using which has a nice animation too:

[image]

Oh and I read somewhere that you can't use Games.API with Auth.API.

EDIT: I got the code implemented correctly by following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) and the login has already the Google Play Games animation, but now my problem that I am trying to resolve is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the last error fixed by just linking the same game again since you can't delete linked apps and using a tester account.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line in your GoogleApiClient initialization.
`.addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)`

It should look something like this:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .build();
```

Comment: But that way it wont give the user option to choose email account?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's already discussed in your given documentation specifically in [Start the sign-in flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#start_the_sign-in_flow).

> In the activity's `onClick` method, handle sign-in button taps by creating a sign-in intent with the `getSignInIntent` method, and starting the intent with `startActivityForResult`.

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
SignInActivity.java
```

> **Starting the intent prompts the user to select a Google account to sign in with.**

More information regarding `intent` can be found in [GoogleSignInApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi).

And, with regards to design specification for various Google Play games services which will be used to add some style and animation, please note of [Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/games/services/branding-guidelines).

Comment: I looked around and found that you can't use Games.API with Auth.API and that I actully don't even need the Auth.API, so I tried something with the BaseGameUtil-s library(without the BaseGameActivity and GameHelper) and it already has the login animation.